# How to control resolution screen size

Tags: android

I'm a new dev of android and I can't control the resolution of the size for screen phone.

I created 2 emulations phone: Pixel 2 1920x1080px 5inch and Nexus 4 1280x760px.

I also created the layout resource w480dp.

When I run test the layout, it only change on pixel 2, the Nexus 4 doesn't change. I also run test on real phone (Galaxy S3), the layout is not same with Pixel 2

So I would like to ask the helping how do I control the resolution screen size. 
I've already read on Google help about small, large... but also can't control in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this library for setting same screen for different device.
[SDP - a scalable size unit](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Comment: I'm not expert about code and studying so that why I want to use simple from code to understand. Can you please?